# How do I install (anything) on debian: 'apt is unknown instruction' in Dockerfile

Tags: debian, docker, wget, apt, apt-get

How do I install (anything) on **debian**: 'apt is unknown instruction' in **Dockerfile**

If I search: [**how to install wget on debian**]

I set articles that say:

`$sudo apt install wget`

---

So I try to do that in Docker:

```
FROM debain
apt install wget
```

and I get this error

```
/full/path/to/current/working/directory                          
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 102B                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                              0.0s 
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 2: unknown instruction: 
                                                                                                                                  
APT                                                                                                                               
/full/path/to/current/working/directory
```

--
what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Valid steps in a Dockerfile include `FROM`, `COPY`, `RUN`, `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, etc. The reference on the syntax is available at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

For your file I'd also recommend looking at the [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run), which would steer you towards:

```
FROM debain
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
      wget \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```